# Listview Onclick Listener Not working after updating Cardview Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have updated the layout, replaced the ImageViews with Buttons instaed, and the Listview OnCLick listener is not working now, when I used the old layout with ImageViews. Please let me know if this needs to be further formatted properly, any help will be approciated.

**Listener in Activity:**

```
lvItem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Position", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ItemNametv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item : "
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qtytv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Qty : "
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/EditItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Edit"
                    android:minWidth="0dp"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/DeleteItem"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Delete"
                    android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                    android:minWidth="0dp"
                    android:minHeight="0dp"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ItemDetailsAdapter.java:**

```
public class ItemDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Item> arrayListItem;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ItemDetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> arrayListItem) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayListItem = arrayListItem;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayListItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayListItem.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        Holder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.ItemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemNametv);
            holder.qty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qtytv);
            holder.EditItem = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.EditItem);
            holder.DeleteItem = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.DeleteItem);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else {
            holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.ItemName.setText(arrayListItem.get(position).getItem());
        holder.qty.setText(arrayListItem.get(position).getQty());
        holder.EditItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AddOrUpdateItem.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra("Position", position);
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.DeleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ShowConfirmDialog(context, position);
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    class Holder {
        TextView ItemName, qty;
        Button DeleteItem, EditItem;
    }

    public static void ShowConfirmDialog(Context context, final int position) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MainActivity.getInstance().deleteItem(position);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is frowned upon in StackOverflow to have links to code. You will likely have a better experience if you include the code by editing your question. You should also consider what is written here [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the section entitled **Help others reproduce the problem**

Comment: @MileT Apologies, I never knew this, I'll update the question with actual code.

Comment: Yes please - external links are OK as supporting information, but the relevant bits need also to be in the question itself, formatted in a readable fashion. The reason for this is that, in our experience, external links often break, leaving the question (and any answers) in a broken state. At that point it has to be deleted in order to maintain a level of site quality.

Comment: (If you repair the question and it has already been put on hold, ping me with `@halfer` and I will consider casting a reopen vote).

Comment: @halfer, I have tried several times adding the code, but I keeps throwing a error that there is a format error in the code, hence I am unable to update the question, I'll try to figure this out again now, hopefully I can format it properly, and update.

Comment: @halfer, please let me know if the question needs further editing, and thank you for the patience.

Comment: @FayazAralikatti what's issue here ? Any error or just dont respong to touch event?

Comment: When I click on the list item, it should start a intent, like it used to when I had the xml with imageviews, since the interface wasn't user friendly, i changed it to buttons,  the buttons work but list view listener is not working,  its not responding to touch event

Comment: There is no error though

Comment: there might be issue of view's conflict i.e. views might be getting over lapped by others so add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" on your parent layout and list item and for all views for which you want to handle click android:focusable="false" add this as well like here in button...

Comment: @halfer I'll try this and update you.

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder Thank you so much, your answer worked perfectly!

Comment: Once again happy to help :) i will post answer you can accept ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue of views getting in conflict i.e. views might be getting over lapped by others so add

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your parent layout and list item and for all views for which you want to handle click events, for them, `android:focusable="false"` add this as well like here in button...

Comment: Glad to help buddy :)

Comment: Can I tag you, for any further questions in future?

Comment: @FayazAralikatti yesh sure :)

Answer (score 1):

TRY this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: In **list_item.xml**, add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your root `Linearlayout`.
- Step 2: In **list_item.xml**, add `android: focusable="false"` to `android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

*Note:* If there is `android:clickable="true"` in `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` remove it.