# Android app won't work in some of the devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar

I created a app which displays firebase childs. It's working in my phone (nexus 6) and works in another (one plus 3), but when I installed it in other devices like a redmi note 3, the app force closes, I am not sure why this is happening.

Logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
    at com.fayaz.uniabex.ItemDetailsAdapter.getView(ItemDetailsAdapter.java:58)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1281)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1188)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18811)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2127)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1243)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1479)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1134)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6045)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:608)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5442)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Here is my git repository  [Uniabex app](https://github.com/fayazara/Uniabex-Materials)

Here is the Card view layout, there are no buttons in it, as I had removed the buttons yesterday and updated with ImageViews

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ItemNametv"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/item_nam" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/EditItem"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:contentDescription="Edit"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_mode_edit_black_18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="end">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qtytv"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/qty" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/DeleteItem"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="14dp"
                android:contentDescription="Delete"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_delete_black_18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

ItemDetailsAdapter.java

```
package com.fayaz.uniabex;

    /**
     * Created by Fayaz on 21/12/2016.
     */

    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ItemDetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private ArrayList<Item> arrayListItem;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public ItemDetailsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> arrayListItem) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayListItem = arrayListItem;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayListItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayListItem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Holder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.ItemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ItemNametv);
        holder.qty = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.qtytv);
        holder.EditItem = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.EditItem);
        holder.DeleteItem = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.DeleteItem);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.ItemName.setText(arrayListItem.get(position).getItem());
    holder.qty.setText(arrayListItem.get(position).getQty());
    holder.EditItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,AddOrUpdateItem.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("Position", position);
            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    holder.DeleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ShowConfirmDialog(context, position);
        }
    });
    return v;
}

class Holder {
    TextView ItemName,qty;
    ImageView DeleteItem, EditItem;
}

public static void ShowConfirmDialog(Context context, final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MainActivity.getInstance().deleteItem(position);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Comment: you are trying to cast an ImageView into a Button is what it seems from your error. Post the relavant code

Comment: @KostasDrak I have updated the question with the code, I don't have Buttons in it.

Comment: Code looks ok, clean, re build then run on Xiaomi again....

Comment: @MuhammadFaisalHyder Thanks, I re built the code, its working now, a little question, how to I mark this as the answer, new to this community.

Comment: Glad to help, i am posting an answer below so you can accept it :) comments can not be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, issue arises in IDEs that they make mess of assigned ids and project needs need to be rebuilt, clean and even invalidate cache and restart in some cases. As in this case, as well, code looks ok, clean, re-build then run your app on Xiaomi again.

Comment: Could you please also help me out with this one [Question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41316964/listview-onclick-listener-not-working-after-updating-cardview-layout)